# Android: Facebook SDK for Android crashes with Nullpointer in Class UserSettingsManager

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook SDK crashes randomly, 
it doesn't give any info regarding what this crash is about; 
we don't even know the action when this is happening and we are not able to reproduce this.

Gradle setting

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

We are using facebook sbk to send events to FB analytics

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.json.JSONObject.optBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
   at com.facebook.UserSettingsManager$1.run(UserSettingsManager.java:148)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue. Equally clueless.

Comment: i'm here too because of same crash

Comment: found the issue reported on official FB bug tacker. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/799308333748606/

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue and there are a lot of crash reports because of this.

Comment: it seems that the NpE has been fixed at line 148 ...see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/UserSettingsManager.java ... do you know if the app get  automatically fixed by gradle  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' or not  ?

Comment: @LucaRocchi if they have released it (not the code fix, but they should publish the package )and if gradle is in online mode then this fix should be available in your next build

Comment: Same issue. Sadly, we discovered this after already shipping out, somehow it wasn’t crashing during our tests. Now we have the biggest crash issue we ever had on production in three years...

Answer (score 6):

According to [this reply](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/799308333748606/?disable_redirect=0) from Marc Hayek of the Facebook team, we may upgrade the version to fix the issue.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.41.0'
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

After some investigation i realized that the bug has been introduced in sdk 4.40
so i have changed gradle to 
`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.39.0'`
and that should remove the bug until a fixed newer FB sdk will be released

Comment: Have the same problem on this version also

Comment: i can only say my crashlytics reports stops to report that crash from days since i deployed the fix

Comment: i checked facebook library 4.41.0 code. it checks for null in the library.